# Unable to get HTML className of selected text using vanilla Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am developing a wysiwyg editor and I am unable to undo the effect that I applied earlier.

Example: If I select some text and bold it, it works fine. But if I want to remove the bold effect on it, I am unable to get the className applied to the selected text. (line # 6 in JS) In the console, I can see that it actually exists under `sel > anchorNode > nextElementSibling > className` but not sure why it is not allowing to fetch that.

```js
function replaceSelectedText(className) {
    var selectedText, sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        
        // check if selection has a class
        if(sel.anchorNode){
            console.dir(sel);
            if(sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling){
                console.log("className:" + sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className);
            }
        }
        
        selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
        //console.log(selectedText);
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var element = document.createElement('span');
            element.className = className;
            element.textContent = selectedText;
            range.insertNode(element);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = replacementText;
    }
}

var toolbarButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#toolbar button");
//console.log(toolbarButtons);
for (var i = 0; i < toolbarButtons.length; ++i) {
    toolbarButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        replaceSelectedText(this.id);
        console.log(document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML);
    });
}
```

```css
#editable{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
    <button id="bold">Bold</button>
    <button id="italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

How do I get the className in Chrome?

Comment: Your code works in Firefox 37: `className:bold`

Comment: @mhu How do I get it working in Chrome?

Comment: I found out that `sel.anchorNode.parentElement.className` works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: You should probably check for type of node. Seems that in most of my tests the anchorNode is the text being selected (textnode) and if that is the case you could check for the parentElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be individual solutions for Chrome and Firefox.

*Firefox*: `sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className`
*Chrome*: `sel.baseNode.parentElement.className`

I fixed it by detecting the browser.

**Detecting the browser:**

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
```

**JS Conditions:**

```
    if(isChrome){
        if(sel.baseNode.parentElement.className){
            console.log("isChrome className:" + sel.baseNode.parentElement.className);
            sel.baseNode.parentElement.className = "";
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(isFirefox){
        if(sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling){
            console.log("isFirefox className:" + sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className);
            sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/590tcmqz/12/